# Can I publish my own continent or pantheon on the Dungeon Master's Guild?

Tags: dnd-5e, publishing, dms-guild

The [Dungeon Master's Guild](http://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/articles/217520927-Ownership-and-License-OGL-Questions) says:

> Under the DMs Guild program, you can publish D&D material that either
>
> - has no setting or
> - uses the Forgotten Realms or Ravenloft setting.

So, let's assume that I'm running a game in the "Shadowfell" which entails a homebrew continent that doesn't exist in the Forgotten Realms canon?

Furthermore, what if it has a pantheon of gods that doesn't exist in the Forgotten Realms canon?

Clearly, it's not canonically "the Shadowfell," but other than that it functions the way that the Shadowfell does. **Are either of these modifications generic enough that I could publish them under the Dungeon Master's Guild?**

Comment: I suggest you submit this question directly to DM's Guild and, when you've gotten an answer, post it here. I've found them to be responsive and helpful.

Comment: Okay, what's the best way to contact them?

Comment: At the bottom of that page there's a [submit a request](http://support.dmsguild.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) link.

Comment: Alternate routes: from DM's Guild frontpage there's a "Contact Us" button at the bottom; there's also an FAQ link down there worth poking through. On FAQ pages there's a "submit a request" link in the header.

Answer (score 18):

From the page you linked: publish my original campaign world using 5th Edition rules: OGL (Yes), DM Guild (No).

Once you say that "Clearly, it's not canonically 'the Shadowfell'," you're saying, "this is my own campaign world", and is not acceptable under the DM Guild. You clearly have *a* setting (so don't fall under bullet one), and that setting is clearly *not* Forgotten Realms or Ravenloft (so don't fall under bullet two).

This post does not constitute nor does it contain legal advice, that by submitting to DM's Guild one is entering into a legal agreement with OneBookshelf and with WotC, and you should be cautious soliciting legal advice from (well-intentioned and well-informed) strangers.

Comment: +1.  You could try and pretend it's "an unknown part of Faerun with different gods!" but I wouldn't expect that to fly if anyone bothers to review the product. It might skate by under the radar but you'd be taking a large risk.

Comment: Ultimately, the practical problem will be that if it's unpopular, it will skate under the radar; but it's unpopular, so there wasn't much point in publishing it. But if it's popular, yay! Oh wait there's the ban hammer.